# What are the guidelines for holes in joists?

Tags: joists

I've been unable to find a good reference for the size/amount/location of holes I can drill through joists.  This is mostly in order to pass cabling or pipes through the joist crosswise.  Also, what about notching the bottom, is there a size threshold there as well?

Comment: In the UK, phone up your local building reg department and they will tell y ou.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Have a look at [this document](https://mybuildingpermit.com/sites/default/files/inline-files/2015%20Tip%20Sheet%2011%20Notching%20Boring%20Framing%20Members.pdf) for a quick reference.  This type of thing will be covered by International Building Code (IBC) and International Residential Code (IRC)

> **IBC 2308.8.2 Framing details.**
>
> Joists shall be supported laterally at the ends and at each support by
>   solid blocking  except where the ends of the joists are nailed to a
>   header, band or rim joist or to an adjoining stud or by other means. 
>   Solid blocking shall not be less than 2 inches (51mm) in thickness and
>   the full depth of the joist. Notches on the ends of  joists shall not
>   exceed one-fourth the joist depth. Holes bored in joists shall not be
>   within 2 inches (51 mm) of the top or  bottom of the joist, and the
>   diameter of any such hole shall not exceed one-third the depth of the
>   joist. Notches in the top  or bottom of joists shall not exceed
>   one-sixth the depth and shall not be located in the middle third of
>   the span.
>
> **IRC R502.8 Drilling and notching.**
>
> Structural floor members shall not be cut, bored or notched in excess
>   of the limitations  specified in this section. See Figure R502.8.
>
> [image]
>
> **IRC R502.8.1 Sawn lumber.**
>
> Notches in solid lumber joists, rafters and beams shall not exceed
>   one-sixth of the depth of the  member, shall not be longer than
>   one-third of the depth of the member and shall not be located in the
>   middle one-third of  the span. Notches at the ends of the member shall
>   not exceed one-fourth the depth of the member. The tension side of
>   members 4 inches (102 mm) or greater in nominal thickness shall not be
>   notched except at the ends of the members. The diameter of holes bored
>   or cut into members shall not exceed one-third the depth of the
>   member. Holes shall not be closer  than 2 inches (51 mm) to the top or
>   bottom of the member, or to any other hole located in the member.
>   Where the  member is also notched, the hole shall not be closer than 2
>   inches (51 mm) to the notch.
>
> **IRC R502.8.2 Engineered wood products.**
>
> Cuts, notches and holes bored in trusses, laminated veneer lumber, gluelaminated members or I-joists are not permitted unless the effects
>   of such penetrations are specifically considered in the  design of the
>   member.
>
> **IRC R602.6 Drilling and notching - studs.**
>
> Any stud in an exterior wall or bearing partition may be cut or
>   notched to a depth not exceeding 25 percent of its width. Studs in
>   nonbearing partitions may be notched to a depth not to exceed 40
>   percent  of a single stud width. Any stud may be bored or drilled,
>   provided that the diameter of the resulting hole is no greater than 
>   40 percent of the stud width, the edge of the hole is no closer than
>   5/8 inch (15.9 mm) to the edge of the stud, and the  hole is not
>   located in the same section as a cut or notch. See Figures R602.6(1)
>   and R602.6(2).
>
> ***Exceptions:***
>
> 1. A stud may be bored to a diameter not exceeding 60 percent of its width, provided that such studs located in exterior  walls or bearing
>      partitions are doubled and that not more than two successive studs are
>      bored.
> 2. Approved stud shoes may be used when installed in accordance with the manufacturers recommendation.
>
> [image]
>
> **IRC R602.6.1 Drilling and notching of top plate.**
>
> When piping or ductwork is placed in or partly in an exterior wall or
>   interi- or load-bearingwall, necessitating cutting, drilling or
>   notching of the top plate by more than 50 percent of its width, a
>   galvanized metal tie of not less than 0.054 inches thick (1.37mm)
>   (16ga) and 11/2 inches (38mm) wide shall be fastened  to each plate
>   across and to each side of the opening with not less than eight 16d
>   nails at each side or equivalent. See  Figure R602.6.1.
>
> ***Exception:*** When the entire side of the wall with the notch or cut is covered by wood structural panel sheathing
>
> **IRC R802.7 Cutting and notching.**
>
> Structural roof members shall not be cut, bored or notched in excess
>   of the limitations  specified in this section.
>
> **IRC R802.7.1 Sawn lumber.**
>
> Notches in solid lumber joists, rafters and beams shall not exceed
>   one-sixth of the depth of the  member, shall not be longer than
>   one-third of the depth of the member and shall not be located in the
>   middle one-third of  the span. Notches at the ends of the member shall
>   not exceed one-fourth the depth of the member. The tension side of 
>   members 4 inches (102 mm) or greater in nominal thickness shall not be
>   notched except at the ends of the members. The  diameter of the holes
>   bored or cut into members shall not exceed one-third the depth of the
>   member. Holes shall not be  closer than 2 inches (51mm) to the top or
>   bottom of the member, or to any other hole located in the member.
>   Where the  member is also notched, the hole shall not be closer than
>   inches (51 mm) to the notch.
>
> ***Exception:*** Notches on cantilevered portions of rafters are permitted provided the dimension of the remaining portion of  the
>   rafter is not less than 4-inch nominal 102
>    mm) and the length of the cantilever does not exceed 24 inches (610mm).
>
> **IRC R802.7.2 Engineered wood products.**
>
> Cuts, notches and holes bored in trusses, structural composite lumber,
>   structural glue-laminated members or I-joists are prohibited except
>   where permitted by the manufacturer’s recommendations or  where the
>   effects of such alterations are specifically considered in the design
>   of the member by a registered design  professional.
>
> [image]