# What are the guidelines for drilling holes through rim or band joists?

Tags: hvac, framing, code-compliance, carpentry

I'd like to bore a 8" hole through 2"x12" rim joist. The hole will be used for a downdraft kitchen vent. Is that 8" hole size ok and up to code?

There are [guidelines](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10657/what-are-the-guidelines-for-holes-in-joists) for boring holes and notches in regular joist, however, are there any guidelines or codes for drilling holes in rim or band joists?

Comment: Check out the answer to this question on Stack: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/18619/do-the-guidelines-for-holes-in-joists-apply-to-band-joists

Comment: Yes, but is there any code for drilling holes in band joists?

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen an issue with cutting through a band joist. HVAC guys will gut a whole section with reckless abandon, so it seems. If you are not cutting into the joists, you will be fine. I never had an inspector cite a band joist not being cut properly.

It might be wise to make the hole so there are at least 2 joists at least on one side of the cut. The band joists are to stabilize the end of the joists.

I would make the hole larger than 8" for an 8" duct. 8 1/4" minimum. All this assumes the band joist is fully supported by a foundation wall and is not spanning over an area as in going from pier to pier...