# How should I finish the area around the gas line for my range?

Tags: kitchens, finishing

We are remodeling our kitchen and had a new gas line run for our range.  What's the best way to finish the area around the valve?  We'll obviously will need to access the valve and run flex pipe from the end.  Should I simply frame the top with another 2x4 and end the drywall there?  Is there a box that would fit this scenario?

[image: Detail of Valve and Terminated End of Gas Pipe]

Comment: Your gas fitter is a jerk. He should have put the valve outside the wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have them come back, remove the valve, and install an elbow and a short nipple so the valve is outside the wall (make sure it's out far enough so that it's outside the finished wall). Then have them install the valve again.

If you know what you're doing, you could do the work yourself, but I don't recommend it.

Unfortunately the pipe bends the wrong way after the last elbow, otherwise you might be able to give it a quarter turn so that the elbow pointed out into the room. In your situation, however, this would loosen the joint, so it's not recommended.

Comment: By code, the valve must be on the exterior of the wall.