# U.S. NEC on adding wires in a finished ceiling

Tags: electrical, ceiling, construction

I want to add a second outlet to my finished garage ceiling, about 14 feet from the existing box. The DIY info I found has all been about adding wires to finished walls.

The question is how to get past joists in the ceiling. If these were studs, then I would put a pumpkin cut in the wallboard next to the stud and drill a pass-through hole in the stud. I wouldn't expect any significant weakness to be added. But I think the ceiling joist may be different, since these joists appear to be part of a truss and are under tension. (Probably not a lot, but I want to be code compliant when I make holes.) I don't know the dimensions of the joists, but I'm guessing 2x10 or 2x12. The picture below shows construction over a much smaller room, where I had a pinhole leak in the pipe.

If I were to do this so it complies with construction and electrical codes, what codes would I be looking for? Apart from that, what is the recommended method for passing the wire through or around the joist in a finished ceiling?

[image]

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/10661/33) might be helpful.

Comment: It's not really electrical code (which is happy if you are at least 1-1/4" from the edge of the framing) it's a structural issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the first question would be if you have a engineered truss system or ceiling joists; they aren't the same thing (as I've learned).

Is there livable area on top of the garage or an attic/loft?

If they are just ceiling joists you can drill a hole right through the middle of the joists (don't cut out notches). I've done 3/4 inch holes with an auger bit; it would fit two 12/2 wires nicely. Try to keep the holes near the middle.

Comment: "the middle" is important here - any holes should be in the **middle 1/3** of the joist, where the stresses are lowest.

Comment: Yes, there is a very large living space (a single "great room") above. If it's built the same way as in the picture, I figure it is just joists.