# What is the proper hole size to drill through joists for wiring?

Tags: joists, data-wiring, ethernet

I am running CAT6a wire around my house and I was wondering what the maximum hole size I can drill to run cable across the joists in my basement to various rooms. I should measure but the joists are 2 x 8's I believe.

Comment: I assume you are talking about conventional dimensional lumber, not engineered beams, such as LVL or I-joists?

Comment: yes. They appear to be conventional lumber.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to International Residential Code, the maximum diameter of a bored hole in sawn lumber is 1/3 the depth of the board.

See [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/10661/33) for more details.

A 2x8 joist has a depth 7¼", so maximum hole diameter would be 2 13/32" (`7.25" / 3 = 2.41667"`).

Comment: +1 was busy trying to copy illustrations from the res code when I saw your answer. I should have expected that you had us covered.