# Are there any restrictions for drilling holes in solid lumber joists regarding how close to the ends of the joist?

Tags: wiring, code-compliance, drill, joists

I've read to not drill a hole greater than 1/3 the depth of the board (I want to drill a 3/4" hole in a 12" board for wiring, so that won't be an issue) as well as not to do it within two inches of the edges. Mine will be approximately 6" from one end.

Are there any restrictions as to how close to the ends of the board I can go with the hole?

Is the "end" of a joist, one of its "edges" (and therefore any holes must be 2" from the end)?

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/10661/33) should have the information you're looking for.

Comment: Though there may also be local code or convention. If in doubt, ask the Local Authority Haning Jurisdiction -- the town inspector's office, for example, since that's who the final approval.

Answer (score 2):

It has to be at least 2" away from the top, or bottom of the joist. As far as distance from the ends, there are no rules:

> Holes: Do not bore holes closer than 2" from joist edges, nor make them larger than 1/3 the depth of the joist. –[engineering.purdue.edu](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~jliu/courses/CE479/extras/Notching_&_Boring_Guide_A11.pdf), PDF

If you look at the document, it clearly states and depicts the top or bottom, with no mention of an "end".